# Rails action not responding to Java POST

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails-3, http-post, httpurlconnection

Really simple, or so I thought.

#### Java Code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class UrlConnectionTest {

    private static final String TEST_URL = "http://localhost:3000/test/hitme";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        URLConnection urlCon = null;
        URL url = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(TEST_URL);
            urlCon = url.openConnection();
            urlCon.setDoOutput(true);
            urlCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");            
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(urlCon.getOutputStream());
            osw.write("HELLO WORLD");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        } finally {
            if (osw != null) {
                osw.close();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

#### TestController#hitme

```
def hitme
  puts "SOMEONE IS HITTING ME!" * 100
  puts request.env.inspect
end
```

When I run the Java code, I see nothing in my Rails Server Console. However, when I hit the URL in my browser, I get output as specified in `TestController#hitme`. I thought it would be simple, but haven't had any luck. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting an exception, which you aren't seeing, because you're swallowing it.  At least print the exception in the catch block.

Even if this isn't the problem, your going to chase your tail a lot if you make a habit of swallowing errors.

---

I don't think you're actually sending any data until you call

```
urlCon.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion. Sorry, that's my mistake. I've actually stepped through this code in Eclipse and did not get an exception. For good measure, I just added `e.printStackTrace()`. Nothing was printed. I'll update my code snippet above to reflect this change.

Comment: That did it! Was that in the API documentation somewhere? If so, would you be kind enough to point it out? In addition to getting the input stream, on the Rails side I had to add `protect_from_forgery :except => [:auth]` to the `TestController` as it was returning at HTTP 422 without it.

Comment: No, I don't see this documented.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that your URL in your java code shows the controller name of "test"  (test/hitme) but you mention that your controller name is TestController?  i.e., the URL in your java code should be changed.

```
   private static final String TEST_URL = "http://localhost:3000/TestController/hitme";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I have mapped my routes the standard Rails-way, that is the word(s) before `Controller` is used as part of the URL. So the URL is correct. A quick test is that it works fine when I hit the URL in my browser.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using something like this for the java http get: // BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
{
sb.append(line);
}
rd.close();

Answer (score 0):

Don't fiddle around with URLConnection yourself, let [Resty](http://beders.github.com/Resty/) handle it.

Here's the code you would need to write (I assume you are getting text back):

```
import static us.monoid.web.Resty.*;
import us.monoid.web.Resty;  
...    
new Resty().text(TEST_URL, content("HELLO WORLD")).toString();
```

Comment: flagged and downvoted for what exactly? For referring to a free, open-source library hosted on github? LOL.

Comment: I upvoted it back to zero. Whoever voted that down with no explanation...lame.